# Conditional choices of an argument based on a preceding argument

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, argparse

I want to create a script that takes two arguments that should be consumed:

- directory_path,
- files -- **the list of files under the directory_path argument**.

I've written something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import os

import argcomplete

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("directory_path",
                        help="a path to some directory",
                        nargs=1)

    # conditional choices of an argument
    conditional_choices = [os.listdir(parser.parse_known_args()[0].directory_path[0])]
    parser.add_argument("files",
                        metavar="FILES",
                        nargs='+',
                        choices=conditional_choices)

    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("directory_path {}".format(args.directory_path))
    print("files {}".format(args.files))
```

So the **files** argument depends on the **directory_path** argument.

Using: Python3.8

## Problems

For the above snippet, the bash-completion (built from **register-python-argcomplete3**) for a **files** argument doesn't work.
If I push enter after the valid command (with path and file) then I'm getting an error

```
error: argument FILES: invalid choice: ...
```

Comment: Does this work without the completer?  While I understand `argparse` well, I haven't done anything with the completer.

Comment: Does the error message include the problem string and the valid choices?  If so, are they what you expect?

Comment: Too many [] in `[os.listdir(...]`.  The error message should list `invalid choice: 'xxx' (choose from '.hdfview2.11', ...` without []

Comment: No, it doesn't work without the completer too. I've recorded how its works on my computer https://asciinema.org/a/QD9t1fA584QwzBkaowZDwM64F 

[In case of asciinema link expired]
If I call 
`sample . stackoverflowfile`
(with the valid file) then I'm getting

`usage: sample [-h] directory_path FILES [FILES ...]
sample: error: argument FILES: invalid choice: 'stackoverflowfile' (choose from ['sample', '.idea', 'stackoverflowfile'])`

Comment: You have generated a bad `choices`.  Compare that with a simple `choices=['one','two']` list.

Comment: Ok, but I would like to have choices of **files** argument that will be dynamically changed based on the value of the **directory_path** argument. So I can't predefine values of choices. If I change choices of files to static `choices=['one','two']` it works (`sample . one` gives valid output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is worth step in **argcomplete** [documentation](https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/index.html) based on which I created a solution

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK

import argparse
import os

import argcomplete


def files_names(prefix, parsed_args, **kwargs):
    absolute_pat = os.path.abspath(parsed_args.directory_path[0])
    files = [file for file in os.listdir(absolute_pat) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(absolute_pat, file))]

    return files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("directory_path",
                        help="a path to some directory",
                        nargs=1)

    parser.add_argument("files",
                        metavar="FILES",
                        nargs='+').completer = files_names

    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("directory_path {}".format(args.directory_path))
    print("files {}".format(args.files))
```

*usesfull [snippet](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/blob/5a20d6165fbb4d4d58559378919b05964870cc16/test/test.py#L276) from argcomplete test directory

To debugging the completion you can set the [**_ARC_DEBUG**](https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/#debugging) variable in your shell to enable verbose debug output